# How can I convert 'form_for' to 'link_to'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters, link-to

```
<%= form_for @order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :quantity, value: 1 %>
<%= f.hidden_field :book_id, value: book.id %>
<%= f.submit %> 
<% end %>
```

Can i do the same with a link_to helper? (create order_item)

For example:

```
<%= link_to 'Create order item',{controller: 'order_items', action: 'create'}, {remote: true, book_id: book.id, quantity: 1} %>
```

I tried above one but error occurred: "param is missing or the value is empty: order_item"

In 'order_items_contrller', in params `:order_item` is required.

Comment: `link_to` is url helper not for form helper. You need create you own helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "Create order item", {controller: 'order_items', action: "create", order_item: {quantity: 1, book_id: book.id}}, method: :post, remote: true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%= link_to "Create order item", {controller: 'order_items', action: 'create', book_id: book.id, quantity: 1 }, :remote => true, method: 'post' %>
```